# SQL left outer join syntax error

Tags: sql, syntax

Im trying to run a query that uses a left outer join but i keep getting a syntax error. Im not sure whats causing it.

```
 SELECT employee.emp_num, employee.emp_lname, pilot.pil_license
 FROM employee LEFT OUTER JOIN pilot
 WHERE employee.emp_num = pilot.emp_num;
```

Comment: Please consider going through an online tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your error is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.". It should be rewritten thus:

```
SELECT employee.emp_num, employee.emp_lname, pilot.pil_license
FROM employee 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pilot ON employee.emp_num = pilot.emp_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "WHERE" by "ON". Only that.

Comment: Do the first thing, not the second as it would result in an inner join using a discouraged syntax.